# How to declare common variable for all action in a asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one asp.net page with next and back button and a variable "i", each time I click next or back button, variable "i" will increase or decrease by 1. So how do I declare variable i?
I don't want to use "public static int i"
Should I use session or viewstate?
Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can use session or viewstate. Never a static field since that value would be the same for every request (user).

Comment: DO NOT use a `Session` variable unless you need to persist the values across pages. If your concern is limited to a particular page then use a `ViewState` variable (wrapped in a property for ease of use), not a Session variable. There are multiple problems involved with use of session variables and are best to avoid wherever possible.

Comment: thank you @TimSchmelter, I know Static variables have Application scope.
Can you tell me about problems you mention @PradeepKumar?

Comment: Session variables with common names like a,b,c or i,j,k etc. can be innocently modified by other pages and you will have a hard time debugging your code. Moreover session variables suffer with timeout problems, which `ViewState` and `Hidden Field` are immune to, since they do a roundtrip. Also, session variables are hard to cleanup once they are no longer required. e.g. you navigate to another page, but your session variable will still be alive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewState` as follows if you want to use it on the same page

```
private int i
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["i"] != null ? (int)ViewState["i"] : 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["i"] = value;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
}

protected void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `View State` is the state of the page and all its controls. It is automatically maintained across posts by the ASP.Net framework.

*Every time the page posts back, it is essentially starting over from scratch - anything initialized to 0, for example, will be zero again. This is because the server doesn't know anything about the last time the page ran - all it knows is you clicked a button which submits a form to that.*

When a page is sent back to the client, the changes in the properties of the page and its controls are determined and stored in the value of a hidden input field named _VIEWSTATE. When the page is again post back the `_VIEWSTATE` field is sent to the server with the HTTP request.

AS on [Incrementing variables in ASP.net on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548421/incrementing-variables-in-asp-net-on-button-click)

> If you need to persist a value across postbacks, the standard method
>   is to use `ViewState`:
>
> ```
> Public Property MyCounter() As Integer
>     Get
>         Dim val As Object = ViewState("MyCounter")
>         Return If(val IsNot Nothing, CInt(val), 0)
>     End Get
>     Set(ByVal value As Integer)
>         ViewState("MyCounter") = value
>     End Set
> End Property
> ```
>
> It's also possible to use Session, which will persist the value across
>   all pages and requests for the life of the user's session. For that to
>   work, you can use the same sample above, replacing ViewState with
>   Session.

Answer (score 0):

A `Session` would be a good idea to store the value.
A session is stored on the server and thus cannot be tampered with.

Note that an ID of the session is stored in a cookie on your computer.
But, even when you disable cookies, your Session would still work as your sessionID will be passed as a `QueryString`in your URL then.

Comment: The person that downvoted this, please let me know why.

Comment: For an explanation for the downvote, please read my comments in the comments section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ajax buttons?

If not and you trying to implement some kind of pagination it is not the best solution. Why not just send new i value in query string?

-include "i" value in url path:

```
 /Page/<i>
```

instead of

```
/Next
```

etc.

If it ajax  - you still able to send "i" value in request body or in querystring.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you need the value of "i" on more than one page:
 I would suggest you to use a `Session` variable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx